# What is the pythonic manner to determine whether this function was successful?

Tags: python, exception, python-2.7

```
def get_connection_tag(connections_tag, connection_type):
    for child in connections_tag.children:
        concat = "".join(child.attributes)
        if connection_type in concat:
            return child
    return -1
```

This function behaves as a search function to find if the specified `connection_type` exists within the `connection_tag`. If it is successful it returns an element from `connections_tag.children`, but if unsuccessful it returns -1.

If the search function was successful I want to call a function to modify this child element, but if it is unsuccessful, I want to call a function to generate a child element.

I could simply call `isinstance()` with the returned child and Class, or I could check to see if the returned `child == -1`, but I feel like I'm missing a more appropriate way. Perhaps something to do with try/except and raising a `TypeError`?

Comment: It's quite weird to return `-1`, it would be better to raise a KeyError or return None.

Comment: Returning -1 is a C thing.

Comment: This function returns after seeing first child, it never loops. Are you sure that's what you need?

Comment: @dan_waterworth I'm new to Python if you hadn't already guessed. I chose to return -1 simply because that is what the string methods do when they fail to find something. I'll certainly change my practice now.

Comment: @zch You're correct, I just noticed that myself. This is untested code, so I didn't notice it immediately. There should be no else and the return should have been nested just outside the for loop.

Comment: Does anyone know why my question is returning -1?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case returning "None" would be more appropriate as it intuitively indicates that no connection was found. Alternatively you could also raise an exception, I usually raise an exception if the execution has to stop  or it's a more serious error.

Based on your use case the code would look like this:

```
tag = get_connection_tag(connections_tag, connection_type)
if not tag:
    pass
```